# Suffrage badge description on the vote-up privilege page is incorrect

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, privileges

The suffrage badge description on the [vote-up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) privilege page is incorrect:

> **Suffrage**: Used *all* 30 votes in a day

The use of the word *all* on that context implies that the max votes per day is 30 (which is not).

The real [suffrage description](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/118/suffrage) is correct though `"Used 30 votes in a day."`

Comment: I guess they missed that when they added Vox Populi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that was a bad line. It's fixed in the meta wiki now. I don't know when those get pushed to all the other sites though. I think it has to be done manually by the SE team.