# Allow suggested edits on privilege wikis

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, privileges

All [privilege pages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges) on MSO are wikis that periodically get pushed out to the entire network. They're also one type of post that doesn't currently work with suggested edits. Apparently you need editing privileges here on MSO to edit them.

Wouldn't it make sense to enable suggested edits for privilege wikis? A lot of users across the network view them. If they notice errors or things that could be improved, they either don't realize that they're community-editable, or they lack the rep to actually carry out improvements themselves — so they [create](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129330/missing-link-on-info-page) new [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129810/suffrage-badge-description-on-the-vote-up-privilege-page-is-incorrect) topics [about](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4127/faq-reputation-info-images-are-low-quality) it.

Comment: +1, and sorry for being the last drop that made your vase overflow :)

Comment: `All privilege pages on MSO are wikis that periodically get pushed out to the entire network` -- *[maniacal laugh, rubs hands together gleefully]*

Comment: So every time somebody gets bent out of shape about a closed post they can edit the 3k page to say "OMG NAZIS"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because privilege wikis haven't been a thing since the modern help center was implemented in 2013.

Answer (score 3):

I think a better approach would be to post suggested changes here on Meta.

Given the visibility of such changes, some community vetting would seem to be in order. One or two edit reviewers checking a box off doesn't really qualify as such.

Comment: You could always specify that you need more reviewers. (i.e. 6 reviewers for each edit).

Comment: Yeah, but the frequency of such changes probably doesn't warrant system enhancements.

Answer (score 2):

Rather, I think the privilege wikis should work like tag wikis:

- anyone can suggest an edit;
- any user with 5000 reputation on Meta can approve a suggested edit;
- any user with 20000 reputation on Meta can make unsupervised edits.

An even more stringent approach would be to make the privileges work like site FAQs, that only moderators can edit, but since there has (as far as I know) never been any abuse, I don't think this is warranted. (Granted, perhaps the absence of abuse is due to nobody knowing that the privilege wikis are editable, which threads like this are changing.)